# CkEditor 5 image upload forbidden 403

Tags: yii2, ckeditor

I am using [this ckeditor](https://github.com/stkevich/yii2-ckeditor5)

but cant upload image. The error I get is `403 forbidden`. Gave `777` permission to my folder but still the same thing. How should I upload an image ? 
Code:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'description')->widget(
     EditorClassic::class, 
     [
         'uploadUrl' => "http://travel.toma.com/backend_images/ckeditor"
     ]
 ); 
?>
```

Comment: `uploadUrl` needs to point to a `.php` file or an `action` in your case

Comment: I changed it but now I get `400 bad request`. Any advice for this ?

Comment: Disabled the `csrf` for the action and it works. But I am not sure this is the right way

Comment: well it aint that simple to send extra param with the request as you need to use the `fileUploadRequest` event to create your call manually and send the file and the extra params

Comment: and the extension you are using isnt that credible the author never responded since `nov 2018` i would suggest you use the https://github.com/2amigos/yii2-ckeditor-widget

Comment: Thank you! I also found it much better